# donet core how to publish my hello world aplication in apache

Tags: asp.net, .net, apache

How do I publish my MVC application Hello World on Apache .

I'm doing some tests with the dotNet core rc2 and found how to publish the application on Apache .

By using the command " dotnet run" the application starts but the equivalent server to IISExpress

tks

Comment: Did you ever get this through ????. Stuck on it.